# Most sustainable way to cool a dorm-room

Tags: cooling

My first year of college has finally ended, and I will be moving from a suite style room to a single room, both student dorming.

My room will have temperature control, however it will be restricted from 65 - 75 (I believe) Fahrenheit (18 - 24 Celsius). I understand that moving the set temperature closer to the outside temperature can help save energy... but will it?

I have so many questions, but I'll just ask one very broad question: **What is the best, most eco-friendly way to cool my windowless dormroom?**

Please consider:

1. Setting my room to the outside temperature might increase the activity of neighboring room thermostats, who are trying to bring it down to a 'comfortable' temperature.
2. If I used a fan, I'd need to use it fairly often. It can get to >100 F (>36 C) easily where I live, in the summer, and easily <40F (<4 C) in the winter.
3. I can't open my window. I have a south-facing window, but it is of a modern type that cannot open (not only south facing but also facing a building, so not much sun at all).

Right now I'm thinking the answer is an energy efficient fan, but perhaps there is some evaporation system that I could use?

I've already read [How to keep a small room cool using wet curtains?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/4380/how-to-keep-a-small-room-cool-using-wet-curtains), but I don't think it answers my question.

Comment: If it is permitted, you could try insulating the south wall from the rest of the room by have heavy drapes along the entire length of the wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The best eco-friendly energy is the one you do not use.

So one of the solution I propose is you **heat your dorm room as little possible** in order to avoid having to cool it down:

- Do not cook in there.
- Use low temperature lights.
- Do not use electronic devices. If you do, shut them down as soon as you can.
- A refrigerator will heat your room far more than you think.
- Take cool showers (and as short as possible, to avoid moisture making the warmness feeling worse).
- Stay outside most of the time, because after all this, you're probably the thing that is heating the most in there.

If you can stand it, it is ok to keep the thermostat as high as possible. It's probably a shared system, so you won't have a big effect on neighbors ones.

*Edit*
Also, if you have a collective air extractor from the bathroom and kitchen, you may use a fan directed towards moist drawers, clothes or towels. By drying (it is necessary for moist to get evacuated if you want this to work), the water will decrease temperature around.

And if it gets unbearable for your health, more advice here: [*keeping-cool-without-air-conditioning.at.greenterrafirma.com*](http://greenterrafirma.com/keeping-cool-without-air-conditioning.html)

Comment: What about for the freezing winters?

Comment: @NeurologicalApex do the contrary. Offer your neighbors to host their server and Bitcoin miners. Use halogen lights. Buy an induction plate and cook extensively. Take hot showers. Invite as much people as possible as often as possible (easy if you cook good food ;).

Comment: @Sylvain, I would have suggested human warmth, and/or warm clothing... But was the question about it? Maybe a huge solar deflector attached in a good place on the facing building?